# Is there a way to include duplicates from MySQL query: select..from..where..id in (list)

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I am trying to get the results for the query type

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(2,4,6,1,1,2) ORDER BY field (id,2,4,6,1,1,2)
```

and I want to get results in the same order as the list including : the duplicates. The above query retains the order but cuts out duplicates. I know I can post-process the results but just wondering if there is an easier way.

Thanks

Comment: i do not understand your question.  the order by looks suspicious, and when you select from somewhere with an in clause you should not 'cut out' the duplicates - you should get them all.

Comment: order by is fine and works. And mysql ought to and DOES cut out dups - try it out.

Comment: I'm also unclear on the purpose of repeating ID 1 in the IN clause. Are you expecting the query to return that row twice?

Comment: An IN() clause is not going to manufacture rows in the result set if that is what you mean by retaining duplicates. In your example, only one row with id = 1 will return no matter how many times you add 1 to the IN() set.

Comment: @Joe, Yes - this id list is generated by an interim process and is expected to contains duplicates. I want duplicates in results too as the output result will eventually be combined with other data that expects both order and dups.

Comment: @Prateek: It's not going to happen the way you expect. The row(s) that match id=1 will only be returned once, no matter how many times the value 1 is repeated in the IN clause. Keep in mind that the IN clause is nothing more than shorthand for: `id=2 OR id=4 OR id=6 OR id=1 OR id=1 OR id=2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will actually achieve what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM table
inner join (
   select 1 as sort, 2 as value union all
   select 2, 4 union all
   select 3, 6 union all
   select 4, 1 union all
   select 5, 1 union all
   select 6, 2) X on X.value=table.id
ORDER BY X.sort
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you building the query?  If you're not opposed to doing a little manual work (which you could later wrap in some code), unions should get you what you need:

```
select id from table where id in (1, 2, 4, 6)
union all
select id from table where id in (6, 8);
```

Returns:

```
------
| id |
|====|
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 4  |
| 6  |
| 6  |
| 8  |
------
```

**EDIT:** Actually, I don't think that helps your ordering, though.  Let me play with this some more.

Comment: That's a nice work around.. however, I think I'll go with post-processing the results.

Comment: You'd have to break the list into uniq sub-lists and pass each of the sub-lists to the order by field (id,sub-list) for each of the unions. (I am assuming that each select statement in the union can take order by).. but as I said, I am gonna leave MySQL alone at this point :)

Comment: Yeah, I played around with it a little, but the ordering becomes nearly impossible.